# How to prepend each line with an instance of a pattern found with awk

Tags: bash, parsing, variables, awk, sed

I have a file with many lines. Some lines display the date and time, e.g. 2022-03-16-08:00

I want all lines following the pattern found to have that pattern prepended

In addition, because there are many lines with different times, I want this to change for every instance of the pattern, and prepend the following lines of that instance with the respective date&time.

For example, I have the following file (example.txt):

```
Date1: 2022-03-16-08:00
Something happened
Something else happened
Date2: 2022-03-16-08:10
Something happened
Something else happened
Something else happened
```

And the result I want is:

```
Date1: 2022-03-16-08:00
2022-03-16-08:00 Something happened
2022-03-16-08:00 Something else happened
Date2: 2022-03-16-08:10
2022-03-16-08:10 Something happened
2022-03-16-08:10 Something else happened
2022-03-16-08:10 Something else happened
```

I tried with sed to prepend the pattern found to each other line, but the sed variable doesn't seem to work:

`sed -e '/2022-/s/\(.*\)/\1/' -e 's/^/$1/' example.txt`

Result:

```
$1Date1: 2022-03-16-08:00
$1Something happened
$1Something else happened
$1Date2: 2022-03-16-08:10
$1Something happened
$1Something else happened
$1Something else happened
```

I thought that it may be feasible with awk, to take the pattern with awk -F: '/2022/{var=$2}'
and then prepend it to the next lines, but I don't know how I would change it to the new instance of Date

Any help is appreciated and very welcome.

Comment: Why do you use `\1` in your first sed command to refer to the first captured sub-expression and `$1` in the second?

Comment: I thought that $1 would have the value taken in the first sed command. But I don't have so much knowledge of those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Date1: 2022-03-16-08:00
Something happened
Something else happened
Date2: 2022-03-16-08:10
Something happened
Something else happened
Something else happened
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"}NF{when=$1;print}!NF{print when,$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
Date1: 2022-03-16-08:00
2022-03-16-08:00 Something happened
2022-03-16-08:00 Something else happened
Date2: 2022-03-16-08:10
2022-03-16-08:10 Something happened
2022-03-16-08:10 Something else happened
2022-03-16-08:10 Something else happened
```

Explanation: Inside `BEGIN` I inform GNU `AWK` using `FPAT` (Field PATtern) that it should consider field to be following string: 4 digits followed by `-` followed by 2 digits followed by `-` followed by 2 digits followed by `-` followed by 2 digits followed by `:` followed by 2 digits, i.e. timestamp compliant with format you are using. For each line if it does contain such file (i.e number of fields that is `NF` is non-zero) do set `when` variable value for content of 1st such field (`$1`) and do `print` current line as is, if there is not such field (`!NF` that is negation of `NF`) then do print `when` variable value followed by whole current line (`$0`).

**Warning**: my code assume that if you have more than one timestamp in single line you want to use first one and there is always timestamp in first line

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e '/: 2[0-9]\{3\}-/{p;s/.*: //;h;d;}' -e 'G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' example.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nejat! It works as it should! Could you please explain a bit to me this part? --> {p;s/.*: //;h;d;}

Comment: @TolisKout `p` prints the pattern space (here, the entire line), `s/.*: //` deletes the text portion from beginning to the `: `, `h` saves the remaining portion to the hold space, `d` deletes the pattern space and starts a new cycle. Note that those commands are executed only if the line read matches the regular expression `: 2[0-9]{3}-`.

Comment: Is there any need to split the commands?  Perhaps `sed -E '/.*(....-..-..-..:..).*/{p;s//\1/;x;d};G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file`?

Comment: @potong No need to split commands with `-e`. Your version would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work in any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ': ' 'NF == 2 && $2 ~ /^20[0-9]{2}/ {
   dt = $2; print; next} {print dt, $0}' file.log

Date1: 2022-03-16-08:00
2022-03-16-08:00 Something happened
2022-03-16-08:00 Something else happened
Date2: 2022-03-16-08:10
2022-03-16-08:10 Something happened
2022-03-16-08:10 Something else happened
2022-03-16-08:10 Something else happened
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){3}:[0-9]{2}/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  print
  next
}
{
  print value,$0
}
'  Input_file
```